# C pipe programming : passing data using a pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I just wrote the following code :-

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

// Create a pipe
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);

int i;

close(0); //close the input to this process
dup(fd[0]); // duplicate the input of this pipe to 0, so that stdin now refers to the input of the pipe

char *test[3] = {"A", "B", "C"};

for ( i=0 ; i < 3; ++i ) {
    write(fd[0], test[i], strlen(test[i]));
    write(fd[0], '\n', 1);
}

execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);

return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to have `sort` take the input from the output of the pipe `fd[1]` and print the sorted output to stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check for errors on system calls.  You'd have seen an EBADF.

```
r = write(fd[0], ...);
if (r == -1 && errno == EBADF) oops();
```

Second, write to the *write* end of the pipe:

```
r = write(fd[1], ...); /* Not fd[0] ! */
```

Third, pass your newline as a *string* not a char:

```
r = write(fd[1], "\n", 1); /* Not '\n' */
```

Fourth, *close* the write end of the pipe when finished, otherwise `sort(1)` will block forever on input that never arrives:

```
for (...) {
  r = write(fd[1], ...);
}
close(fd[1]);

execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
oops_exec_failed();
```